Question on equality of prime-indicator function over different subsets of integers
Let
$$\mathbb{S}=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\ | \gcd(n,6)=1\}=\{1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,29,...\}\tag{1}$$
be the ordered-set of positive integers relatively prime to $6$ and
$$a(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \mathbb{S}(n)\in \mathbb{P} \\
 0 & \text{Otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{2}$$
be the prime-indicator function which returns one when the $n^{th}$ element of $\mathbb{S}$ is a prime and zero otherwise.

I've noticed that
$$a(n)=A246500(n+3),\quad 1\le n\le 296\tag{3}$$
where OEIS entry A246500 is defined as the "Characteristic function of the prime numbers $\bmod 9$ over the set $\{2,4,8,1,5,7\}$".

The equality in (3) above seems an extremely unlikely coincidence to me. Can anyone explain why this equality should hold over such a long range and why it seems to end abruptly at $n=297$ as illustrated in the table below?

In the table below, the $p$ column is the current working value of $p$ in the Mathematica code at the end of this question which is my implementation of OEIS entry A246500. One thing I noticed in the table below is that $\mathbb{S}(n)=p$ when $A246500(n)=1$ for $1\le n \le 296$ which is indicated by asterisks in the last column in the table below.

$$\begin{array}{cccccc}
 n & \mathbb{S}(n) & a(n) & A246500(n+3) & p & \mathbb{S}(n)=p \\
 280 & 839 & 1 & 1 & 839 & * \\
 281 & 841 & 0 & 0 & 853 &   \\
 282 & 845 & 0 & 0 & 853 &   \\
 283 & 847 & 0 & 0 & 853 &   \\
 284 & 851 & 0 & 0 & 853 &   \\
 285 & 853 & 1 & 1 & 853 & * \\
 286 & 857 & 1 & 1 & 857 & * \\
 287 & 859 & 1 & 1 & 859 & * \\
 288 & 863 & 1 & 1 & 863 & * \\
 289 & 865 & 0 & 0 & 877 &   \\
 290 & 869 & 0 & 0 & 877 &   \\
 291 & 871 & 0 & 0 & 877 &   \\
 292 & 875 & 0 & 0 & 877 &   \\
 293 & 877 & 1 & 1 & 877 & * \\
 294 & 881 & 1 & 1 & 881 & * \\
 295 & 883 & 1 & 1 & 883 & * \\
 296 & 887 & 1 & 1 & 887 & * \\
 297 & 889 & 0 & 1 & 907 &   \\
 298 & 893 & 0 & 1 & 911 &   \\
 299 & 895 & 0 & 0 & 919 &   \\
 300 & 899 & 0 & 0 & 919 &   \\
 301 & 901 & 0 & 1 & 919 &   \\
 302 & 905 & 0 & 0 & 929 &   \\
 303 & 907 & 1 & 0 & 929 &   \\
 304 & 911 & 1 & 1 & 929 &   \\
 305 & 913 & 0 & 0 & 937 &   \\
 306 & 917 & 0 & 0 & 937 &   \\
 307 & 919 & 1 & 1 & 937 &   \\
 308 & 923 & 0 & 1 & 941 &   \\
 309 & 925 & 0 & 0 & 947 &   \\
 310 & 929 & 1 & 1 & 947 &   \\
 311 & 931 & 0 & 0 & 953 &   \\
 312 & 935 & 0 & 1 & 953 &   \\
 313 & 937 & 1 & 0 & 967 &   \\
 314 & 941 & 1 & 0 & 967 &   \\
 315 & 943 & 0 & 0 & 967 &   \\
 316 & 947 & 1 & 0 & 967 &   \\
 317 & 949 & 0 & 1 & 967 &   \\
 318 & 953 & 1 & 1 & 971 &   \\
 319 & 955 & 0 & 0 & 977 &   \\
 320 & 959 & 0 & 1 & 977 &   \\
\end{array}$$

The following Mathematica code illustrates my implementation of OEIS entry A246500 which perhaps provides some further insight on its construction. The code below compensates for the fact that Mathematica references the first element of a list with an index of $1$ instead of an index of $0$.

A246500 = Block[{p = 2, j, k = 0, list = {}},
   While[Length[list] < 1000,
    j = Mod[p, 9];
    If[MemberQ[{2, 4, 8, 1, 5, 7}, j],
     While[j != {2, 4, 8, 1, 5, 7}[[k + 1]],
      list = AppendTo[list, 0];
      k = Mod[k + 1, 6]];
     list = AppendTo[list, 1];
     k = Mod[k + 1, 6]];
    p = NextPrime[p]];
   list];


Reducing the elements of $\Bbb{S}$ modulo $9$, one gets ${1,5,7,2,4,8,1,5,7,2,4,8,\dots}$, so the "shift by three" between the two sequences has a simple cause.

... isn't the OEIS sequence defined to be exactly $S(n)$ (other than the shift in index)? As one proceeds over the residue classes $1,5,7,2,4,8$, one encounters precisely the numbers that are $1$ or $5$ modulo $6$.

@EricTowers Thanks for your observation.

@GregMartin The definition of the OEIS sequence is a bit cryptic to me, but $A246500(n+3)$ doesn't exactly match $a(n)$ for $n>296$ unless there's an error in my implementation of one of the functions.

@GregMartin Pehaps you mean the subset of $\mathbb{S}(n)$ where $a(n)=1$ (i.e. the prime elements of $\mathbb{S}(n)$) matches the primes $p$ for which $p \bmod 6 \in {2, 4, 8, 1, 5, 7}$?

I've noticed that $a(n)$ has a string of $6$ zeros starting at $n=297$ and $$a(n)=A246500(n+3-6)=A246500(n-3)$$ for $303\le n\le 377$ where once again $a(n)$ has a string of $6$ zeros starting at $n=378$, so perhaps a modification of OEIS entry A246500 where a string of $6$ zeroes is added under certain conditions will lead to an exact equivalence between $a(n)$ and the modified version of $A246500(n+3)$.
